# Problem with MathieuS[x,x,x] function

Tags: differential-equations

Why Mathematica (13.1) can't find a solution to a differential equation in MathieuS[x,x,x]/MathieuC[x,x,x] form?

[image: img1]

I expect to see a solution to the equation like c1*MathieuC[x,x,x]+c2*MathieuS[x,x,x]
wolfram alpha can produce a differential equation with mathieuS[x,x,x], but DSolve in Mathematica cannot solve it.
[image: img2]

Comment: The two ode's are not the same. The first you have `(a - 2*b*Cos[2*x])*w[x] + w''[x] == 0` and the second you have an extra `x`  as in `x*(a - 2*b*Cos[2*x])*w[x] + w''[x] == 0`. `DSolve` can solve the first one but not the second. Why do you expect that when adding `x` it should still give similar solution in terms of Mathieu functions?

Comment: I just tried the second ode `x*(a - 2*b*Cos[2*x])*w[x] + w''[x] == 0` in Maple 2022.2, and it also was unable to solve it.  Do you happen to know this has analytical solution?